# ESPAsyncWebServer - post request causes crash or 404 message

Tags: html, c++, asynchronous, arduino-esp8266

I'm working with a NodeMCU on the latest version of ESPAsyncWebServer. I was able to have "GET" requests work fine with the near exact same code, but when I tried to modify it as per (what you can call) [the documentation](https://github.com/me-no-dev/ESPAsyncWebServer#get-post-and-file-parameters), I haven't had any luck.

The code below will compile and load the first page at `/setlimits` just fine, but as soon as "Submit" is hit, the NodeMCU crashes with Exception 28. I can post the full stack-dump upon crash, but it's quite a mess.

The other weird thing is, if I remove the `method="post"` from the HTML, it goes instantly to the `handle_NotFound` method and I don't get any data from the post.

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63842519/esp32-asynch-web-server-post-method-not-working) but I feel like our errors are different, plus theirs is way more advanced than my HTML and code.

Any ideas on why it's not working? Or is this a bug that needs to be sent to the developer?

### Minimally reproducible error .ino file with HTML

```c
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESPAsyncTCP.h>
#include <ESPAsyncWebServer.h>

const char* ssid = "NodeMCU";
const char* password = "pa$$word";
String color;
IPAddress local_ip(192,168,1,1);
IPAddress gateway(192,168,1,1);
IPAddress subnet(255,255,255,0);
AsyncWebServer server(80);


const char index_html[] PROGMEM = R"rawliteral(
<!DOCTYPE HTML><html><head>
  <title>ESP Input Form</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head><body>
  <form action="/colors" method="post">
    <label for="favcolor">Select Color for LED 1:</label>
    <input type="color" id="favcolor" name="favcolor" value="#ff0000"><br><br>
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
</body></html>)rawliteral";


void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(115200); /* Initialize serial communication at 115200 */
  WiFi.softAP(ssid, password);
  WiFi.softAPConfig(local_ip, gateway, subnet);
  delay(100);
  server.on("/colors", HTTP_POST, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
    color = request->getParam("favcolor")->value();
    Serial.println("Request gotten!");
    request->send(200, "text/html", "cool"); 
  });
  server.on("/setlimit", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
    request->send_P(200, "text/html", index_html);
  });
  server.onNotFound(handle_NotFound);
  server.begin();
  Serial.println("OK!");
}


void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println(color);
}


void handle_NotFound(AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
  request->send(404, "text/plain", "Not found");
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: test if the parameter exists with `hasParam`

Comment: @Juraj tried that, sadly did not work.

Comment: Post request does not has the params per se. the data are in the response body. See @juraj answer [here](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/56628/40646).